# CUDA Kernel register size

Tags: cuda

On a compute capablility 1.3 GPU  cuda card,
we run the following code

```
for(int i=1;i<20;++i)

kernelrun<<<30,320>>>(...);
```

we know that  each SM has 8 SP and can run 1024 threads,
so there are 30 SM in tesla C1060 which can run 30*1024 threads concurrently.

As per the given code, how many threads can run concurrently ?
If there are 48 registers for the kernelrun kernel , what are the limitations on tesla C1060?

which has 16384 registers and 16KB shared memory?

Since concurrent kernel execution is not supported in Tesla C1060, how 
can we execute the kernel in loop concurrently ? IS streams possible?
only one concurrent copy and execute engine in tesla C1060?

Comment: Just to point out: You have 30 SM and each SM has 8 SP. This means you can run only 240 threads concurrently. Rest will be queued . Period

Comment: @talonmies: Why is the above plain wrong?

Comment: @Programmer: CUDA works like an SIMD architecture with a vector size equal to the warp size, ie 32. A compute 1.x device single issues a warp at a time per SM, and the architecture is pipelined (about 21 instructions). So at any given time a GT200 could have 32 threads per SM on the ALUs, retiring at a maximum rate of every fourth clock, plus more doing data prefetch plus even more on the register file. The total number of threads in some stage of execution simultaneously could be up to 128 warps per SM

Answer (score 1):

NVIDIA have been shipping an [Occupancy calculator](http://news.developer.nvidia.com/2007/03/cuda_occupancy_.html) which you can use to answer this question for yourself since 2007. You should try it.

But to answer your question, each SM in your compute 1.3 device has 16384 registers per SM, so the number of threads per block *if* your kernel is register limited would be roughly 352 (16384/45 rounded down to the nearest 32). There is also a register page allocation granularity to consider.

Comment: i used the occupancy calc and found 320 threads per block having higher occupancy. but when i execute the kernel in loops does it run parallel on 1.3 compute capability or do i have to use OMP or streams? Pls help me

Comment: Your hardware only can run a single kernel at a time and there is nothing you can do to change that. If you launch 10 kernels, they will be queued up by the driver and run sequentially from first to last.

Comment: @taulonmies if i split the data to multi GPU and use each of them as u say sequentially, will there be any performance difference ?

Comment: @Krakesh that depends on your kernel and how much memory transfer is needed to keep data on all gpus consistent. if your kernel has no data dependencies and you can perform a divide and conquer of your problem you can theoretical achieve a linear performance gain factorized by the number of gpus you use.

Comment: @kronos If we use Fermi architecture, how to best implement the kernel loop in 2 cases:  [1] one GPU  [2] multi-GPU